# Внешние службы по хранению и обработке данных

Tags: postgresql, azure, amazon, облако, облачное-хранилище

Есть задача обработать данные - несколько больших таблиц, ни R, ни Python с компа не тянут. Как можно эту задачу решить с помощью внешних служб? Возможно ли подключиться к какому-нибудь доступному облаку, поднятым postgresql базам? Тогда каким? (Своих БД, куда бы я могла подключиться, нет).

Comment: несколько больших таблиц - о каком к-ве записей речь? как сейчас хранятся эти таблицы?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis 20млн строк, сейчас это csv файлы.

Comment: Если столбцов не много и размер базы не будет превышать 10 ГБ - попробуйте использовать MSSQL Express или же версию Developer (в ней нет ограничения на размер базы).

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis установила! Спасибо. Только пока не поняла как оно работает. Создала в менеджере коннекшн к MSSQL ( с драйвером Microsoft). А он ошибку выдаёт - "Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."  И откуда взять login-password, если они нужны?

Comment: Вам нужно подключиться к локальному серверу, который создался при установке MS SQL. Затем создать базу данных и в таблицы в ней импортировать нужные Вам данные.